# Condition for line intersection in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: geometry

While reading through some questions I came across someone stating the following:

> Defining two lines in space, $\mathbb{R}^3$, as:
>
> $l_1: \textbf{a}_1+\lambda_1\textbf{b}_1$
>
> $l_2: \textbf{a}_2+\lambda_2\textbf{b}_2$
>
> The line to line intersection condition is:
> $\textbf{b}_1\cdot ((\textbf{a}_2-\textbf{a}_1)\times\textbf{b}_2)=0$
> which can be rewritten as:
> $\textbf{b}_1\cdot (\textbf{a}_2\times\textbf{b}_2)+\textbf{b}_2\cdot (\textbf{a}_1\times\textbf{b}_1)=0$

Why is this condition sufficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the direction of the common normal (direction perpendicular to **both** lines) as

$$ \boldsymbol{n} = \boldsymbol{b}_1 \times \boldsymbol{b}_2 $$

Now project any point along each line on the common normal and it  will result in a constant value

$$ d_1 = (\boldsymbol{a}_1 + \lambda_1 \boldsymbol{b}_1) \cdot \boldsymbol{n} = \boldsymbol{a}_1 \cdot \boldsymbol{n} $$

$$ d_2 =(\boldsymbol{a}_2 + \lambda_2 \boldsymbol{b}_2) \cdot \boldsymbol{n} =\boldsymbol{a}_2 \cdot \boldsymbol{n} $$

if the two lines intersect then these constants are the same $d_1 = d_2$ since they have at least one point in common.

So the condition is

$$  \boldsymbol{a}_1 \cdot \boldsymbol{n}  =  \boldsymbol{a}_2 \cdot \boldsymbol{n} $$

or

$$  \boldsymbol{a}_1 \cdot ( \boldsymbol{b}_1 \times \boldsymbol{b}_2)  =  \boldsymbol{a}_2 \cdot ( \boldsymbol{b}_1 \times \boldsymbol{b}_2) $$

or

$$ (\boldsymbol{a}_1-\boldsymbol{a}_2)  \cdot (\boldsymbol{b}_1 \times \boldsymbol{b}_2) = 0 $$

Now you can rewrite the above in any other form you want as seen by the answer of Quarter Lemon or in the problem statement, using the identities of the vector triple product $a\cdot(b\times c) = b\cdot(c\times a)=c\cdot(a\times b)$.

Comment: Thank you, I feel like this answer is the easiest one to understand

Answer (score 2):

The actual condition is

$ (\mathbf{a_2 } - \mathbf{a_1} ) \cdot (\mathbf{b_2} \times \mathbf{b_1} ) = 0 $

But since for any three vectors $\mathbf{a,b,c}$,

$ \mathbf{a}\cdot (\mathbf{b} \times \mathbf{c} ) = \mathbf{b}\cdot (\mathbf{c} \times \mathbf{a} ) = \mathbf{c}\cdot (\mathbf{a} \times \mathbf{b} )$

then the above condition can also be written as

$ \mathbf{b_1} \cdot ( (\mathbf{a_2 } - \mathbf{a_1} ) \times \mathbf{b_2}) = 0 $

The last equation in the question can be deduced by expanding the above equation and using the cyclic equality again.

Comment: But how can one show that this condition is equivalent to the lines intersecting?

Comment: The vector perpendicular to both lines has a direction given by $\mathbf{N} = \mathbf{b_2} \times \mathbf{b_1} $.  If the component of the position displacement vector $\mathbf{a_2} - \mathbf{a_1} $ onto vector $\mathbf{N}$ is zero, then the two lines intersect.

Comment: Do you know, how to prove these two statements? And what exactly do you mean by 'component of the position displacement vector'?

Comment: @question by 'component ....' I mean the dot product.  To prove this statement, take the plane that contains the first line and is parallel to the second, it has a normal vector $\mathbf{N}$ that is perpendicular to both direction vectors of the two lines (which are $\mathbf{b_1}$ and $\mathbf{b_2} $ ), therefore, $\mathbf{N} = \mathbf{b_2} \times \mathbf{b_1} $.  The equation of this plane is then $\mathbf{N} \cdot (\mathbf{p} - \mathbf{a_1} ) = 0 $  If the lines intersect, then $\mathbf{a_2}$ must be on this plane.  Hence, we must have $\mathbf{N} \cdot (\mathbf{a_2} - \mathbf{a_1}) = 0 $

Comment: Thank you! I understand it now

Answer (score 1):

The vector $\mathbf{b}_1 \times \mathbf{b}_2$ is perpendicular to both lines. So, after some scaling, if necessary, you can imagine your two lines in a room, with $l_1$ on the floor, $l_2$ on the ceiling, and a vertical line joining them, in the direction $\mathbf{b}_1 \times \mathbf{b}_2$. The vector $\mathbf{a}_1 - \mathbf{a}_2$ joins two points, one on each line. In order for the lines to intersect, the component of this vector in the vertical direction must be zero (i.e. the ceiling must coincide with the floor). In other words, $\mathbf{a}_1  - \mathbf{a}_2$ must be horizontal, which means it’s perpendicular to the vertical direction $\mathbf{b}_1 \times \mathbf{b}_2$. The dot product of any two perpendicular vectors is zero, so $(\mathbf{a}_1 - \mathbf{a}_2) \cdot (\mathbf{b}_1 \times \mathbf{b}_2) = 0$. You can rearrange this equation into either of the ones you cited.